# Setup Zend framework and mod Asp.net in Apache 2.2.21

Tags: asp.net, apache, zend-framework2

I have been trying to install zend framework and mod_aspdotnet in apache 2.2.21. If I only install mod_aspdotnet and not zend then everything works fine and vice versa. I need them to run together. Can anybody suggest me some way to do that. 
Any help is highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.